Error with local variables in recursion in python
I am trying to write a program to find leaf value sequences in python (https://leetcode.com/problems/leaf-similar-trees/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=leetcode-75)
Here is my code
def leaves(root,ans) :
    if(root.left == None and root.right == None) :
        ans.append(root.val)
        return(ans) 
    elif (root.left == None ):
        ans = ans + leaves(root.right,ans)
        return(ans)  
    elif (root.right == None) :
        ans = ans + leaves(root.left,ans)
        return(ans)  
    else :
        ans = ans + leaves(root.left,ans) + leaves(root.right,ans)
        return(ans)    

For the case [1,2,3]  in the 2nd example the function leaves([1,2,3],[]) should return [2,3] but instead returns [2,2,2,3]. I assume that the error is because the variable ans is a global variable. My understanding is that it should be a local variable each time when passed to a function. Please explain if my understanding is correct
Also what corrections do I need to make to the code

You are both passing ans to the recursive calls, and concatenating it with the values returned from those calls.  Do one or the other, not both.

Lists passed as an argument to a function are received as a reference, not as a value. This means that if you modify the list inside a function, its value will also be modified outside the function.
As @jasonharper said, you are modifying the list and returning it, so the values will repeat, just return the current node and its child values.
def leaves(root) :
    if root.left == None and root.right == None:
        return [root.val]
    elif root.left == None:
        return leaves(root.right) 
    elif root.right == None:
        return leaves(root.left)  
    else:
        return leaves(root.left) + leaves(root.right)  

